# Jmeter running in Linux command not returning correctly

Tags: linux, command-line, jmeter

I am trying to run a fairly large monitoring test in jmeter through Linux.

The .jmx file I am using runs and keeps the test running on an infinite loop when run on a GUI version of Jmeter.

To run it on Linux I am using :
`sh jmeter.sh -n -t MasterMonitorNew.jmx -l log.jtl`

but the response I get from the test is:

```
Creating summariser <summary>

Created the tree successfully using MasterMonitorNew.jmx Starting the
test @ Sun Feb 08 18:49:14 EST 2015 (1423439354371) 
Waiting for
possible shutdown message on port 4445
summary =      0 in     0s = ******/s Avg:     0 Min:     0 Max:     0  Err:     0 (0.00%) Tidying up ...    @ Sun Feb 08 18:49:14 EST 2015 (1423439354658) ... end of
run
```

The entire test takes less then 2sec till it shuts itself off, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Anything in jmeter.log?